# TRY CATCH inside of TRANSACTION

Tags: sql-server

I have written a procedure which selects columns from a table and inserts into another table.

I put a try/catch block inside the transaction. If I got any error inbetween then my code will insert error details into error log table and roll back the transaction.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('usp_Stage_raw_ADDM_ALL') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Stage_raw_ADDM_ALL]
    PRINT 'Procedure usp_Stage_raw_ADDM_ALL Dropped'
END
GO

CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_Stage_raw_ADDM_ALL] AS

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION; 

BEGIN TRY
DELETE FROM tbl_Staging_Devices WHERE [Source] LIKE 'ADDM%'
INSERT INTO tbl_Staging_Devices 
(
    Device_Name,
    Serial_Number,
    Company,

)
SELECT [Computer Name] AS Device_Name,
Serial_Number = 
    CASE
        WHEN [Serial Number]='None' THEN NULL
        ELSE [Serial Number]
    END,
Company = 'Car'
FROM (
    Select * From raw_ADDM_PCL
    UNION ALL
    Select * From raw_ADDM_CCL) a

END TRY

   BEGIN CATCH
      IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
        EXEC USP_InsertErrorDetails
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
    END CATCH

   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    IF OBJECT_ID('usp_Stage_raw_ADDM_ALL') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Procedure usp_Stage_raw_ADDM_ALL Created'
END
GO
```

Comment: And your question is....?

Comment: What is the wrong i am doing here.I mean above code is executed successfully.and once i run  select statement against my table tbl_Staging_Devices. My select stmt is running and not returning nay records.

Comment: I don't know. Do you get any errors? Unexpected behaviour? What do you expect and what happens? Only dumping your code without any further information is not very helpful. Please edit your question and add some more details.

Comment: Hello Ocaso,
As i mention in my question that..I need to insert the error details like msg,id,severity and other details to my errorlog table if i get any error while executing the SP also i want to roll back the transaction which is i write at TRY block.

Comment: Ahh, now I understand. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 that should help

Comment: I got above code from there only ,but its not working as expected.

Comment: Bro, I'm seeing `EXEC USP_InsertErrorDetails` coming directly before `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`, doesn't that mean the effects of that SP will also get rolled back?

Comment: Hay,
I don't know that.I am not getting any error at any SP or at execution of any SP.But once my parent sp executed successfully and i run simple select in to my table staging devices..this select will run run and run......not returning any resutes nor any error.

Comment: It doesn't finish? Or it finishes without results?

Answer (score 4):

All that the sp you created does is

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
```

Your code is divided in batches using GO, and your SP's code is only that one:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_Stage_raw_ADDM_ALL] AS
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
```

You cannot insert "go" inside your procedure, "go" means the batch is finished, the code is submitted to server, and now you submit the CREATE PROC code with only 1 statement

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[usp_Stage_raw_ADDM_ALL] 
AS
BEGIN

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

BEGIN TRY
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DELETE FROM tbl_Staging_Devices WHERE [Device_Name] LIKE 'ADDM%'

INSERT INTO tbl_Staging_Devices 
(
Device_Name,
Serial_Number,
Company
)
SELECT [Computer Name] AS Device_Name,
Serial_Number = 
CASE
WHEN [Serial Number]='None' THEN NULL
ELSE [Serial Number]
END,
Company = 'Car'
FROM (
Select * From raw_ADDM_PCL
UNION ALL
Select * From raw_ADDM_CCL) a
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY

   BEGIN CATCH
      IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
        EXEC USP_InsertErrorDetails
   ROLLBACK TRANSACTION; 
END CATCH
END
```

Comment: Comparison to OP code: (1) `BEGIN TRAN` now before `BEGIN TRY`. (2) `COMMIT TRAN` now before `END TRY`. (3) Disposed of `PRINT` related segments (*not problem related*).